# Can't install JDK from Oracle on Jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, java-8, build

I defined in Jenkins JDK->install automatically-> selected JDK version -> I agree

But when i ran a build the JDK installation fails with this error

```
 [jdk] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk/jdk.sh -noregister
/var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/jdk/jdk.sh: 2: Syntax error: newline unexpected

Can you please help?
```

I tried to run a build with JDK+maven
I expected to see the jdk 1.9 being installed running
Thanks

Comment: `1.9`? Or do you mean `19`?

Answer (score 5):

If was experiencing the same issue, try the following steps to resolve it:

1. Go to Jenkins > Manage Plugins.
2. Locate the plugin "Oracle Java SE Development Kit Installer."
3. Click "Uninstall" and confirm the action.
4. Restart your machine.

This should fix the error. 
It's unclear why this particular plugin causes the issue, but removing it seems to resolve it.
 To prevent the error from returning, make sure not to reinstall the plugin. (ITS WEIRD I KNOW)

Comment: Must login for a vote!!! Not sure how you found it. But that's a magic!

Answer (score 0):

If your using Ubuntu OS. use below steps or Linux use Yum command to install Openjdk1.8*

This is known bug currently. Please follow below steps to solve it.

SSH to jenkins and run below command.

sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk -y

Login to Jenkins

Go to Manage Jenkins => Global Tool Configuration

Click on JDK Installation => Click on Red Cross mark on the right to remove Any JDK you have

Click on Add JDK => uncheck Install automatically option

In name add below line

OracleJDK8

In JAVA_HOME add below line and save.

/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

Answer (score 0):

I found openjdk istalled on my machine at this location
/opt/java/openjdk/bin

Add  /opt/java/openjdk/bin in java_home location